# insert column as header for type

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySql table and I want to list things by type and insert headers. What type of query would I use?

From This:

```
| Fluffy   | Harold | cat        | f    | 1993-02-04 | NULL       |
| Claws    | Gwen   | cat        | m    | 1994-03-17 | NULL       |
| Buffy    | Harold | dog        | f    | 1989-05-13 | NULL       |
| Fang     | Benny  | dog        | m    | 1990-08-27 | NULL       |
| Bowser   | Diane  | dog        | m    | 1979-08-31 | 1995-07-29 |
| Chirpy   | Gwen   | bird       | f    | 1998-09-11 | NULL       |
| Whistler | Gwen   | bird       | f    | 1997-12-09 | NULL       |
| Slim     | Benny  | snake      | m    | 1996-04-29 | NULL       |
| Dalli    | Alli   | canine     | m    | 2001-12-20 | NULL       |
| Tara     | David  | canine     | f    | 2002-05-17 | NULL       |
| Mimi     | Alli   | guinea pig | m    | 2004-05-17 | NULL       |
```

To this:

```
<h2>Cat</h2>

<ul>
<li>Fluffy</li>
<li>Claws</li>
</ul>

<h2>Dog</h2>

<li>Buffy</li>
<li>Fang</li>
<li>Bowser</li>
</ul>
```

etc.

Comment: Probably want to do an `order by type` then you will need to construct the list with php.

Comment: hmmm... possibly they are of the family Canidae though so they may in fact be coyotes or wolves or something of that nature?

Comment: Do it with two loops in PHP. One: get `DISTINCT` types of animals, second: inside each type display all animals that have this type

Comment: This is presentation logic -- I would not try to do this via SQL.  Just ORDER BY the type column.

Comment: @Edga Could you show an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to do all of this with SQL (just do a standard select query), use PHP to group the result, then present it. The best way to do this would be to have an object that will do the grouping for you, as you'll probably need it more than once. For example, your class could look something like this:

```
<?php
class Arrays
{
    public static function group($array,$key)
    {
        if(NULL == $array)
            return NULL;

        $grouped = NULL;

        foreach($array as $item)
        {
            $grouped[$item[$key]][] = $item;
        }

        return $grouped;
    }
}
?>
```

And your use case could be something like:

```
<?php
$result = ...; // The result of your database query.

$grouped_by_type = Arrays::group($result,"type");

foreach($grouped_by_type as $type => $group)
{
    echo "<h2>".ucwords($type)."</h2>";
    echo "<ul>";

    foreach($group as $animal)
    {
        echo "<li>".$animal['first_name']."</li>"; // Assumes the query brought back first_name...
    }

    echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first query would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type FROM table ORDER BY type ASC
```

With your PHP, I am sure you can get a result from this query and loop through it. Next one is to put another query inside the loop that gives you the list of animals that belong to current type:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE type='$type' ORDER BY name ASC
```

`$type` is just variable holding current type. I assumed column and table names so please change it to suit your code.

Comment: If you have 1000 types of animal, you're going to run 1001 database queries. It will solve the problem, but it's not a good solution to apply, at least not in 99% of cases anyway.

Comment: Perhaps it would have been best to add this as a comment rather than an answer then - I don't know, I'm new to SO so I don't really know what the best practice is. Given that this is now the accepted answer, the OP (and others reading) will presumably be doing what you've said - and potentially apply the same solution to other problems he/she comes across, which IMO isn't right! :)

Comment: I didn't specify any approach. I gave the SQL code ONLY. I always prefer for people to have a play first with something instead having been given a solution straight ahead. Especially if it's something helpful. Besides, nothing wrong with looping like that: `$r = mysqli_query($q); while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){}` which is, if you must know, what I intended to propose later on